# Inconsistent image sizing across applications

Tags: resolution, scaling

I have a 3200 x 1600, 276 ppi display, and I have noticed that images do not appear not be the same size across applications. What could be the cause of this? In the picture below, I have opened the same image in Windows Photo Viewer, Photoshop, Firefox, and Chrome.

[image: Image size varies across applications]

Edit:

It turns out that I had my display at 200%. This was the result when I switched it to 100%:

[image]

That still doesn't explain the initial discrepancy though.

Answer (score 1):

This should have to do with your display DPI and default printing DPI. Some programs may decide to render the image correctly on the screen, presumably at 96 DPI or so. Other programs decide to display you the picture the same way it will look when you print it, at 300 DPI or so. Thus the difference in size. Yet other programs may disregard the DPI setting completely and reset your image DPI to the screen DPI.

In order to know which is your case, you should post:

1. Your screen's DPI value
2. Your default printer's DPI value
3. Actual size of your image (length in pixels / 276)
4. Size of your image as it is displayed by each program